# arcpy.da.SearchCursor not work when run the whole scripts in IDLE

Tags: arcpy, cursor, runtimeerror

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1. The code is running in IDLE of winpython 2.7 64bit.
Here is a very simple code which intends to read a shapefile.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workplace = "E:/"
shpfile = "landuse.shp"
polygonlist=[]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor( shpfile,("SHAPE@") ) as cursor:
    for line in cursor:
        polygonlist.append( line[0] )
```

When I run the script file with IDLE, it failed with "RuntimeError: cannot open 'landuse.shp'. " of the "with arcpy.da.SearchCursor( shpfile,("SHAPE@",col) ) as cursor:"

However, when I type the script lines one by one into the IDLE shell. It worked just fine.

When I run the script file in Spyder. It ended with the same error at the first time. But I just press F5 for another try, it worked fine.

I really want to know why.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect your error is that:

```
env.workplace = "E:/"
```

should be:

```
env.workspace = "E:/"
```

Comment: It's weird that the script glossed over env.workplace and returned an error on the search cursor.. I would have expected an error like *env has no property 'workplace'*. Are we sure that landuse.shp is in E drive with the path 'E:\\landuse.shp'? What happens if you comment out the workspace line and change to the full path shpfile = 'E:\\landuse.shp'?

Comment: @MichaelStimson In Python, attributes can be added to objects at any time during execution. This is normal behavior. This makes it important to qualify information in error messages. For example, the `RuntimeError` should probably name the workspace explicitly, so that the user can see it wasn't set.